# Match multiple times in the string

Tags: php, regex, string

How can I get all matches in a string?
For example, a string is

```
hhh (12) 5cb (jkl) jj
```

or

```
brt (11) {
```

I want to get *12* and *jkl* in first string and *11* in second one.

I tried

```
preg_match("/.*\((.*)\).*/", $input_line, $output_array);
```

but this get only last match in a string.

Answer (score 2):

The RegEx you are looking for should be something like this:

```
preg_match_all("/\((.*?)\)/", $input_line, $output_array);
```

[Live example.](https://regex101.com/r/vG4iO4/1)

Explanation:

```
  (.*)     #grab all characters
  (.*?)    #as little as possible
\((.*?)\)  #that are within brackets
```

You also need to use `preg_match_all` instead of `preg_match` so that you get all the strings that match the pattern.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but php writes "Unknown modifier 'g'"

Answer (score 0):

Use [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) instead of `preg_match`. It returns a 2-dimensional array with information from each match.

You also need to fix the regexp. Take out the `.*` around the parentheses, because that's making it match everything else in the string, so there's just a single match. And inside the parentheses you need to use a non-greedy quantifier, so it won't match beyond the close parenthesis.

```
$input_line = 'hhh (12) 5cb (jkl) jj';
preg_match_all("/.*\((.*?)\).*/", $input_line, $output_array);
print_r($output_array[1]); // array of all the capture group 1
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/7Ya8ZJ)